Non-split exact sequence of locally free sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^1$
$\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}$
On  $\mathbb{P}^1_k$, This question gives that $Ext^1(O_X(2), O_X) = H^1(O(-2)) \neq 0$, so there should be a non-split exact sequence of the form $O \ra O_X \ra F \ra O_X(2) \ra 0$. Then, $F$ is locally free of rank 2. I want to compute a transition matrix and describe the morphisms in the exact sequence.
Let $a$ be $y/x \in k[x/y]_{y/x} = O_X(D(x) \cap D(y)) $. The transition matrix for $F$ is of the form  $\begin{pmatrix}1 & ? \\ 0 & a^2 \end{pmatrix} $, but I don't know what to put in the $?$. I'm guessing it's $a$.  I think the first morphism $O_X \ra F$ is inclusion into the first component (under a trivialization $F|_U \simeq O_U^2$, but then what is the second map $F \ra O_X(2)$? It can't be projection since the exact sequence is non-split.

F is O(1) + O(1)

The nonsplit extension is the Euler sequence
$$0\to\mathcal O \to \mathcal O(1)^{\oplus 2} \to \mathcal O(2)\to0$$
which is described via graded modules as: $$0\to S\overset{\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix}}\to S[1]^{\oplus 2} \overset{\begin{pmatrix}y&-x\end{pmatrix}}\longrightarrow S[2]\to0$$
The transition map of the sequence on $A=k[t,t^{-1}]$ can be written as
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
0 & \rightarrow & A & \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix}1\\t\end{pmatrix}} & A^{\oplus 2} & \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix}t&-1\end{pmatrix}} & A & \rightarrow & 0 \\
  &             & \downarrow{1} &  & \downarrow{t^{-1}I_2} &  & \downarrow{t^{-2}} &  &   \\
0 & \rightarrow & A & \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix}t^{-1}\\1\end{pmatrix}} & A^{\oplus 2}& \xrightarrow{\begin{pmatrix}1&-t^{-1}\end{pmatrix}} & A & \rightarrow & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

Thank you, although I expect the transition matrix to be of the form \begin{pmatrix}1 & ? \ 0 & a^2 \end{pmatrix} (Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, 14.3.G). The transition matrix for $O(1) \oplus O(1)$ is \begin{pmatrix}a & 0 \ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}. How do we get those two transition matrices to be the same?

@David Lui That transition matrix would imply that there is a projection map back $F\to \mathcal O$, which would split the sequence, hence it would be trivial in Ext.

The previous comment is including the assumption from OP that the first map is inclusion into a first summand by the way. Even if that assumption is dropped, $\mathcal O(1)^{\oplus 2}$ still can't have a transition matrix like that due to krull-schmidt theorems for vector bundles, or in case of $\mathbb P^1$ just by classification.

The transition map in this answer $t^{-1}I_2$ matches the one from Vakil
